# Валидация checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.
Нужно проверить отмечен ли checkbox на странице и убрать атрибут у submit - disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="mods[]">

<input type="submit" class="but" disabled="disabled">

    $('#check:input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        $('.but').removeAttr('disabled');  
    }else{
        $('.but').attr('disabled', true);  
    }
});
```

Код работает только на 1 checkbox, т.е. кликнув на 2 и следующие ничего не произойдёт. Как сделать, чтобы код работал на все checkbox.

Почему не могу использовать `class="check"`, они заняты и в зависимости от категории меняются

Почему не могу использовать `input:checkbox`, на странице присутствуют другие checkbox

Comment: "В пределах одной страницы, НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ два и более элемента с одинаковым ID!" Это в рамочку и повесить над рабочим местом.

Comment: я знаю, просто добавил для наглядности

Comment: @innot20, Для... наглядности??? Даже боюсь узнать объяснение :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID уникален, если что, учи маны.
[Так?](https://jsfiddle.net/y6jqgj75/)

Comment: Можно попроще - https://jsfiddle.net/y6jqgj75/1/

Comment: Я люблю функциональное программирование, но оно точно не для новичков, которые даже азов не знают, поэтому так и написал.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="123123 check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" class="dffd check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" class="adfsd check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" class="hfh check" name="mods[]">
<input type="checkbox" class="sdfasd check" name="mods[]">

<input type="submit" class="but" disabled="disabled">

$('.check:input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        $('.but').removeAttr('disabled');  
    }else{
        $('.but').attr('disabled', true);  
    }
});
```

Не знал, что можно прописать два класса